# How to share the text of a meeting between the attendants in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook, calendar, meetings

Is there a way to create a meeting in Outlook in a way that every attendant can edit the meeting text to include his own points to the meeting agenda?

As far as I know by default only the creator can edit the meeting text (not sure if I'm right about this).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the sender of the invite is the only one that can update the text for all others.

Each participant can edit his own copy, but it doesn't go anywhere.

The best solution would be to include a link in the invite to a place where shared editing is supported - could be SharePoint, a website, a simple Word doc or Excel sheet on a LAN drive, etc.

Comment: Seems a lack of a common feature if you ask me.